# US Census: bivariate chloropleth of total population (ACS 2013) and total jobs (LEHD 2012)

Tags: cartography, census, united-states

The most recent ACS data available is 2013 and Tiger data is also available for 2013. The most recent LEHD data available is 2012 and the geography crosswalk files join it to Tiger 2010 data.

Given that the Tiger files are from different years, is it possible (cartographically sound) to map ACS total population data and LEHD data (WAC, if you're curious) together?

Comment: Yes, please clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  The more context, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the geographic boundary change notes from the Census Bureau.  I believe blocks, block groups and tracks' geometry are updated every 10 years with a new census. https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/boundary-changes.html

Also checkout the **User Notes** from each year in the Tiger/line info https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html